# ACF doesn't save calculated value to custom field in a custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom taxonomy named `papers`. I've add a custom field (with ACF) named `year_number` that comes from the union of two other fields.
Now I'm trying to save that field within the taxonomy term and I've tried the following but it won't work. Where am I wrong?

```
function my_acf_update_year_number($term_id)
{
        $value = get_field('year') . get_field('number');
        $field_name = "year_number";
        update_field($term_id, $field_name, $value);
}
add_action('edit_term', 'my_acf_update_year_number');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `acf/update_value` hook of the ACF to update the year_number field.

```
function update_year_number(  $value, $post_id, $field ) {
      if ( 'year_number' === $field ) {
         $value = get_field('year') . get_field('number');
         update_field( $field_name, $value, $post_id);
       }
}
add_action( 'acf/update_value', 'update_year_number', 10, 3);
```